# How can I edit the source code for an R function?

Tags: r

I am working with the `earlywarnings` package, and would like to edit one of the functions written in the `qda_ews` function.  I could do `fix(...)` but the function I would like to edit is for some reason not listed when I use `fix`.

The function is called `generic_RShiny`.  Here is the link to the github (https://github.com/earlywarningtoolbox/earlywarnings-R/blob/master/earlywarnings/R/qda_ews.R).

How can I access the entire `qda_ews.R` code to make the changes I need?

Comment: You can get the function code with `getAnywhere(generic_RShiny)`. To edit it, you could paste it into a R script file, make your edits, assign it to a new object (like `my_generic_RShiny`) then run your new version of the function.

Comment: If you want to have the edited function available in the future, you could either save the script of the edited function and then `source` it when you need it, or you could create your own version of the `earlywarnings` package with the edited version of the function and then install/load your custom version of the package.

Comment: Seems like part of the problem may be [`generic_RShiny` is not exported](https://github.com/earlywarningtoolbox/earlywarnings-R/blob/master/earlywarnings/NAMESPACE); have you tried appending `earlywarnings:::generic_RShiny` to your approach using `fix`?

Answer (score 5):

once the library is loaded, use

`trace(name_of_function, edit = T)`

but beware that the function will be modified permanently (until of course you reinstall the package)

Comment: I edited a function using this method, but it doesn't seem to work with knitting Rmd into html file. Is there another method I can use?

Comment: If you want to use the changed method with knitting from Rmd. Copy the method using @baskcat answer, then paste it into your Rmd and edit it. Then instead of calling the library function, call the method from your Rmd.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but  I was actually looking for function 'body' to change code lines of function. Here's an example to change the second line of this function 'my_fun'

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  a <- 2
  b <- 5
  return(a*x+b)
}
my_fun(2)
# 9

body(my_fun)[[2]] <- substitute(a <- 3)

my_fun(2)
# 11
```